# c# wpf анимация

Tags: c#, wpf, анимация

Нужно запилить анимацию для своего текстбокса. Где то в коде я должен буду прописать команду, например `mytextbox.Error()`, по которой запустится анимация текстбокса. Сама анимация заключается в том, что при вызове определенной команды границы текстбокса должны в течении 1 секунды перекраситься в красный цвет.

Что то напилил, но Exception:

```
System.ArgumentException: "Параметр AnimationTimeline типа "System.Windows.Media.Animation.ColorAnimation" нельзя использовать для анимации свойства "BorderBrush" типа "System.Windows.Media.Brush".
Имя параметра: animation"



public void Error()
    {
        ColorAnimation erranim = new ColorAnimation();
        erranim.To = Color.FromRgb(226, 70, 71); //вот тут ругается
        erranim.Duration = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1);
        dd.BeginAnimation(BorderBrushProperty, erranim);
    }
```

Comment: А что простите анимация, в WPF проекте, делает в коде? Ей там не место. Научитесь делать привязки и поймите что такое XAML, а лучше поймите MVVM подход.

Comment: Вся остальная анимация у меня в XAML коде, однако эта анимация должна запускаться по команде, в `RoutedEvent` нет подходящего для меня триггера событий. Научитесь то, научитесь это. Я как раз сюда учиться и пришел, а так информацию ищу в открытых источниках. Но, к сожалению, конкретно по этому вопросу не нашел.

Comment: Понимаете в чем дело... Я не просто так говорю, что вы должны научиться делать это так-то, ибо вы вот задали два вопроса по анимациям и оба они решаются просто - свойство и триггер, все. Зачем вот вам тут событие? К примеру у вас статус сервера и в случае если он вышел из сети, надо плавно сменить цвет с зеленого на красный, как быть? Нужно ли событие? Нет... Делаете в классе сервера `bool` свойство `IsOnline` и привязываете его, делая при `true` анимацию на зеленый цвета, а при `false` на красный. Все, вам достаточно в коде теперь менять одно значение `IsOnline = true;`, все.

Comment: Вот по этому я вам и говорю, ну поймите вы что такое привязки, хотя бы базовые вещи, это просто, очень. А потом поймите что такое подход MVVM и вы узнаете, что в коде любые UI элементы быть не должны. По этим двум аспектам даже здесь, на SO уйма ответов (включая и от меня), я уж не говорю про другие порталы.

Comment: Хорошо, спасибо за совет!

Comment: Я вам дам потом ответ на тот ваш вопрос, покажу как с привязками и прочим сделать плавную смену цвета, а этот вопрос уж извините, ищите сами ответ, ибо для меня это тихий ужас)